# Mysql match, against is not returning proper results

Tags: mysql

I am trying this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE MATCH(`field_name`)
AGAINST('+san +city' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

I want to get all records that should contain san city, but the result is different. In result am getting all records that contain "city" like "Pearl City, Salt lake city etc".
What I am doing wrong.

Comment: Well its a fulltext search, that is why it showing all city results. Why do not use like clause if you want search only "san city" result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the MATCH in your `SELECT`-part of your query to get a grip on how MySQL works here:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(field_name) AGAINST('+san +city' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
FROM table_name 
WHERE MATCH(field_name) AGAINST('+san +city' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

You will see the priority in this column.

Keep in mind that your results differ if you're using MyISAM and MySQL < 5.6 or InnoDB and MySQL => 5.6. [Here's a good article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/03/04/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-2-the-queries/) about it.

Comment: Well I am using this query instead of match, against query: 
SELECT field_name FROM table_name WHERE (field_name LIKE '%city%' AND field_name LIKE '%sun%');
and I am getting my desire results

Comment: You can do that, but this isn't a fulltext search then. Whatever suits your needs best!

Comment: Yup its not full text search, anyways thanks for your kind help